# How to make Datatables sort by images (boolean)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

So my question is pretty straight forward. I have a column in Datatables for 'favorite'. This column has a star image you can toggle on or off (so, true or false). I need datatables to sort this column by whether this row is favorited or not. I am using the Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons, so the class being toggled is glyphicon-star or glyphicon-star-empty. How can I configure this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom sorting plugin. See the examples in the documentation at https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/sorting_sType.html.

The essence of it should be

```
$(td).hasClass('glyphicon-star');
```